# Forcing an ANSI edit control instead of the comctl32 edit control

Tags: c, winapi, window, controls, comctl32

I built up a module that creates a window with an edit box from windows' EDIT windowclass. It is designed to only work with ansi character set and not using any unicode.

I make use of [EM_GETHANDLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761576%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to recieve the buffer to the edit control.

Now here is my problem: (quoted from link above)

`Note  For Comctl32.dll version 6, the buffer always contains an array of WCHARs, regardless of whether an ANSI or Unicode function created the edit control. For more information on DLL versions, see Common Control Versions.`

So when my module gets loaded by an application that has comctl32 initialized, my whole code breaks.

My Question: Is there a way to prevent CreateWindowA to use comclt32 or does anyone have an idea to fix this problem?

Comment: Your answer for prevention is in the quoted text. What's so problematic with Unicode, especially if you're not going to support it in full anyway? Just throw away or ignore what you cannot handle or better yet give the user an error message when they enter something that you don't want to handle, e.g. non-ASCII chars.

Answer (score 1):

The application uses `COMCTL32.DLL` if it is specified in the app's manifest as described e.g. here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

If your module is DLL, then you might try use some isolation technique so it does not rely on what version of `COMCTL32.DLL` the .exe decided to use, but that might bring many other drawbacks.

I recommend to use `WM_GETTEXTA` or `GetWindowTextA()` instead, which will copy converted string into your buffer. Designing a module which requires old version of a DLL to work correctly is simply bad idea.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I need to use `EM_GETHANDLE`, because I use that handle to access the control's buffer directly and also write to it (I know that I may not do this!).

I guess I need to use CreateWindowW for the edit control to resolve my problem.

Comment: Alternatively, use `IsWindowUnicode()` to determine whether the Edit window was created by `CreateWindowA()` or `CreateWindowW()` and then adjust your buffer logic to use `CHAR` or `WCHAR` accordingly.